# When is Mongock undo expected

Tags: mongodb, mongock

I am starting to use Mongock for mnongoDB migrations.

I was wondering when is the 'Undo' feature for Mongock may be expected? It is a very important feature

Thanks

Comment: Asking for a possible feature release date.

Answer (score 0):

UNDO feature will be released in the next version 5.
We haven't decided a release date yet but will probably **around May**. We are not planning to deliver any new features for version 4.

However, please drop us an email to dev@cloudyrock.io explaining your needs, so we can try to find a solution for you.